# How to align Spinner in Actionbar to left

Tags: android-actionbar, spinner

[image]

I want to align the spinner to left. spinner is not used for navigation here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@android:id/text1"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:ellipsize="marquee"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:textColor="@color/white"
      android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Grab the actionbar, then:

```
actionbar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```